# Want to get different Cookies from Incognito and Normal Windows

Tags: node.js, session, cookies, nuxt.js, express-session

This is my session code and it creates multiple session IDs as the SSR requests are not sending the cookies in the header. I have tried setting the cookies for SSR request and it was successful. But both incognito and normal windows sending different cookies, i am getting the normal window's session value in incognito window too. For example if i access subdomain a.hvx.com in normal window, it creates a session id and when i open b.hvx.com it is using the same session of the a.hvx.com. How to prevent this or how can i send or get different cookies from normal and incognito windows?

The above is my session code and it creates multiple session IDs as the SSR requests are not sending the cookies in the header. I have tried setting the cookies for SSR request and it was successful. But both incognito and normal windows sending different cookies, i am getting the normal window's session value in incognito window too. For example if i access subdomain a.hvx.com in normal window, it creates a session id and when i open b.hvx.com it is using the same session of the a.hvx.com. How to prevent this or how can i send or get different cookies from normal and incognito windows?

`app.use( session({ store: new RedisStore(constantValue.redisConst), secret: "HVX", resave: false, proxy: true, saveUninitialized: false, cookie: { // httpOnly: parseInt(configINI().SSL.enabled) === 1 ? false : true, httpOnly: true, secure: parseInt(configINI().SSL.enabled) === 1 ? true : false, maxAge: 3600000 * 60, // domain: navigator.userAgent.indexOf('Incognito') !== -1 ? '.incognito.example.com' : '.example.com' }, }) )`